# How to order distinct tuples in a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

I'm trying to submit a query in Postgres that only returns distinct tuples. In my sample query, I do not want duplicate entries where an entry exists multiple times for a cluster_id/feed_id combination. If I do a simple:

```
select distinct on (cluster_info.cluster_id, feed_id) 
   cluster_info.cluster_id, num_docs, feed_id, url_time 
   from url_info 
   join cluster_info on (cluster_info.cluster_id = url_info.cluster_id) 
   where feed_id in (select pot_seeder from potentials) 
   and num_docs > 5 and url_time > '2012-04-16';
```

I get just that, but I'd also like to group according to `num_docs`. So, when I do the following:

```
select distinct on (cluster_info.cluster_id, feed_id) 
   cluster_info.cluster_id, num_docs, feed_id, url_time 
   from url_info join cluster_info 
   on (cluster_info.cluster_id = url_info.cluster_id) 
   where feed_id in (select pot_seeder from potentials) 
   and num_docs > 5 and url_time > '2012-04-16' 
   order by num_docs desc;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: select distinct on (cluster_info.cluster_id, feed_id) cluste...
```

I think I understand why I'm getting the error (cannot group by tuples unless I explicitly describe the group somehow) but how do I do that? Or if I am incorrect in my interpretation of the error, is there a way to accomplish my initial goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The leftmost `ORDER BY` items cannot disagree with the items of the `DISTINCT` clause. I quote [the manual about `DISTINCT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> The `DISTINCT ON` expression(s) must match the leftmost `ORDER BY`
>   expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional
>   expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within
>   each `DISTINCT ON` group.

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.cluster_id, feed_id) 
           c.cluster_id, num_docs, feed_id, url_time 
    FROM   url_info u
    JOIN   cluster_info c ON (c.cluster_id = u.cluster_id) 
    WHERE  feed_id IN (SELECT pot_seeder FROM potentials) 
    AND    num_docs > 5
    AND    url_time > '2012-04-16'
    ORDER  BY c.cluster_id, feed_id, num_docs, url_time
           -- first columns match DISTINCT
           -- the rest to pick certain values for dupes
           -- or did you want to pick random values for dupes?
    ) x
ORDER  BY num_docs DESC;
```

Or use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.cluster_id
     , num_docs
     , feed_id
     , url_time 
FROM   url_info u
JOIN   cluster_info c ON (c.cluster_id = u.cluster_id) 
WHERE  feed_id IN (SELECT pot_seeder FROM potentials) 
AND    num_docs > 5
AND    url_time > '2012-04-16'
GROUP  BY c.cluster_id, feed_id 
ORDER  BY num_docs DESC;
```

If `c.cluster_id, feed_id`  are the primary key columns of all (both in this case) tables that you include columns from in the `SELECT` list, then this just works with PostgreSQL **9.1** or later.

Else you need to `GROUP BY` the rest of the columns or aggregate or provide more information.

Comment: I think I need the GROUP BY as you mentioned as I'm getting the following error with your second answer:  ERROR:  column "c.num_docs" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Your first answer gives the following error:  ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 3:     SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.cluster_id, feed_id)

Comment: @WildBill: You may have missed the update on the first query. I fixed a mistake in my first version. As to the second query: If you provided the missing information which columns belong to which table and which primary keys and your version of PostgreSQL, my answer could be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your help and references!

Comment: This was insanely slow for a table with just 28M rows in it... Is there a faster solution? After a join there's a lot of duplicates on the variation in column values. We want to order by these columns and return distinct rows based on the primary key (id). Doesn't seem to be a performance acceptable way of doing it...